# Import-Module : The specified module 'activedirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0

I am having trouble doing an import-module ActiveDirectory on a Server 2008 SP2 (64 bit).

- NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is installed
- I download the Windows6.0-KB968934-x86.msu (for ADWS)
- This file did not install saying that "The update does not apply to my system"
- Doing some research (http://anti-american.rssing.com/chan-2091246/all_p15.html) I installed hotfix in KB article 969166 and the above update installed.
- After a reboot, I noticed that in services, Active Directory Web Services is running
- I opened an administrative PS prompt and performed an Import-Module ActiveDirectory, but...

...I get:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'activedirectory' was not loaded because no valid     module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  activedirectory
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (activedirectory:String) [Import-    Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

If its any help, here's some info in PSModule Path, modules and the version:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\ischmd\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Module -ListAvailable

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}

PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.psversion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1


PS C:\Windows\system32> $host.version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The main purpose of this is to GET-AdUser command to automate some process but at this point, were stumped. My only conclusion is that this is not possible with Windows 2008 SP2...

Comment: Install is a two step process - once you run that KB install, you have to open Add/Remove programs/Add Windows features and select the AD components to install.

Comment: In Server 2008, Add Windows features takes you to the Server Manager. Under features I Go to "Remote Server Admin Tools" and "Active Directory Domain Services Tools" inc controller tools is already installed. 

I dont see anything with regards to ACtive Directory and powershell. Note: Windows Powershell appears installed in the features menu.

Comment: @KidBomba did you got this resolved ?

Answer (score 42):

AD Powershell module should be listed under installed Features. See image:

[image: AD Powershell module should be listed under installed Features.].

Comment: This option is not present in Windows Server 2008..... I think the screenshot above is 2008 R2...

Comment: This exists in `Windows Server 2012`

Comment: For Windows 7 these options will be present after installing the Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Answer (score 33):

For non-servers this requires **Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows __**

- Windows 7: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887
- Windows 8: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972
- Windows 10: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: I have been using this module occasionally for months, but it suddenly quit working.  I didn't make the connection that the company pushed out an update from Windows 10 1803 to Windows 10 2016.  I had to reinstall the module for the new OS version.

Comment: In Windows 10 Pro 1909, and probably in most non-server builds, a lot of the stuff on this page didn't work, and I instead had to do this, which I found on a number of other articles with a caveat:
`Add-WindowsCapability –online –Name “Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0”`

should be changed to just
`Add-WindowsCapability –online –Name “Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools”`

I did this after downloading and installing the RSAT `msu` from the bottom link above.

Answer (score 15):

The `ActiveDirectory` module for powershell can be installed by adding the `RSAT-AD-Powershell` feature.

In an elevated powershell window:

```
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

or

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName ActiveDirectory-Powershell -Online -All
```

Comment: ActiveDirectory-Powershell  not found

Comment: what does Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName ActiveDirectory-Powershell -Online -All do?

Answer (score 11):

You can install the Active Directory snap-in with Powershell on Windows Server 2012 using the following command:

**Install-windowsfeature -name AD-Domain-Services –IncludeManagementTools**

This helped me when I had problems with the Features screen due to AppFabric and Windows Update errors.

Comment: This will install quite a bit more than just the management tools.  The specific feature required is `RSAT-AD-Powershell`.

Comment: Quite a bit more - it adds the Domain controller bits.  Seems overkill!

Comment: Install-windowsfeature : The term 'Install-windowsfeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Even better use implicit remoting to use a module from another Machine!

```
$s = New-PSSession Server-Name
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession -Session $s -Module ActiveDirectory -Prefix REM
```

This will allow you to use the module off a remote PC for as long as the PSSession is connected.

More Information:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720181.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old post, but if anyone is still facing this issue after trying all the above mentioned steps, ensure whether the default path of PowerShell module is specified under the `PSModulePath` environment variable.

The default path should be `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 - This happened for me after the latest update in 2020.

What solved this issue for me was running the following in PowerShell

```
C:\>Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the Active Directory module installed on your machine, you need to download the correct Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) package for your OS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools#rsat-for-windows-10-platform-and-tools-support-matrix

If you are running windows 10 you can download Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10 update from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Once installed run 'import-module ActiveDirectory' using elevated PowerShell.