# How to get user Data from LDAP Active Directory located on another server using PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I want to get data of Active Directory located on another server. I have server details but I don't know how to get use it. However, I know how to get data if I run PowerShell Script from same server.

Here is links from there I got code to get data which works fine if I get data by PowerShell Script located from same server. Can anybody please suggest me how can I get data from Active Directory located on another server?

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-script-to-5edcdaea

http://woshub.com/get-aduser-getting-active-directory-users-data-via-powershell/

Comment: You've **just asked** this same question only 2 hours ago - please **DO NOT** post the same question over and over and over again!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I will apply your answer today. I will surely react on result. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, As there is some server issue from my side, I am not able to connect. I am resolving that first. Your reference looks fine. However, I will check again once all the issues done from server side. Thanks

Comment: @NanjiMange - You may like to upvote the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to upvote an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is almost a duplicate of your previous question about "[How to add/update user data to LDAP Active Directory located on another server using PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759120/how-to-add-update-user-data-to-ldap-active-directory-located-on-another-server-u)".

You need to additionally use the `-Server <string>` parameter to connect to other server with your `Get-ADUser` cmdlets.

> How to get user Data from LDAP Active located on another server
>   directory using PowerShell Script?

You've already used the cmdlet `Get-ADUser` in the flagged duplicate. I'm showing a sample example below on finding all active user-objects and their properties:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $Username) -And (Enabled -eq 'True')} -Server a.b.c.d | Select-Object *
```