# The specified module ActiveDirectory was not loaded

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

I have an SSIS job that executes a powershell module that's attempting to pull information from Active Directory.  However, when I run the script I get this error:

> The specified module ActiveDirectory was not loaded because no valid
>   module file was found in any module directory

I found this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182497/import-module-the-specified-module-activedirectory-was-not-loaded-because-no) question, however they are using Windows Server 2008, whereas I am using Windows Server 2016.  I tried to follow the instructions in the question, but I wasn't able to locate neither "Remote Server Administration Tools" nor "Active Directory module for Windows Powershell."

Comment: Is the RSAT role enabled on your server?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how do i check that?  i'm not really a server admin

Comment: `Get-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT, RSAT-Role-Tools, RSAT-AD-Tools, RSAT-AD-PowerShell`

Comment: If these are not enabled, use `Add-WindowsFeature` to enable them and you will have the `ActiveDirectory` module available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check whether **Active Directory Web Services** service is running under services?

If not start it and run below command

```
Get-module -list
```

You can check whether Active Directory module is listed down.

Run below command to Enable Active Directory module

```
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

Comment: https://www.ntweekly.com/2016/07/03/install-active-directory-powershell-module-on-windows-server-2016/  came across this link, might help you.

Comment: how do i start Active Directory Web Services?  i'm not really a server admin

Comment: @DForck42 open services.msc and look for the Active Directory Web Services

Comment: @DForck42 did you run the PowerShell command Add-WindowdFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell?

Comment: i looked under services and i do not see Active Directory Web Services

Comment: @DForck42 Here is how to enable RSAT . https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/02/26/install-the-active-directory-powershell-module-on-windows-10/

Comment: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName RSATClient-Roles-AD-Powershell`